# Credentials or role for Auth0 talking to AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, auth0

I have an API Gateway where all the resources methods are secured using AWS_IAM as the Auth type.

When I try it using Postman, I generate a SigV4 using my Access Key and Secret Access Key.

Now I want to allow Auth0 to make a post request to one of the endpoints and I don't know if I should create keys and generate a SigV4 or a role. I read about roles but, it is not clear for me how I would do it with Auth0. I will appreciate help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more? Do you need that Auth0 backend connect to API Gateway or do you need that users registered in Auth0 connect to your REST endpoint?